# google direction gives 0 values

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-directory-api

hey I have used google direction to get duration it's working but sometime it return 0 value to json array routs. when I tested a day after return a value. is there any limitation for google direction request per day ?

and here is my function to get duration

```html
public String getDistanceInfo(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

   // Destination of route
   String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

   String dura = "";
   try {

    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String output = "json";
    String mode = "mode=walking";
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode;

    // Output format


    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


    //String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + str_origin + "," + str_dest + "&destination=" + destinationAddress + "&mode=driving&sensor=false";

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


    response = client.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
    int b;
    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
     stringBuilder.append((char) b);
    }
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   } catch (IOException e) {
   }

   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   try {

    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

    JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);

    JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");

    JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);

    JSONObject duration = steps.getJSONObject("duration");
    dura = duration.getString("text");

   } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return dura;
  }
```

```html
org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)
org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:282)
org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:510)
```

Comment: If it gives a zero values .. the reason could be there is no possible path

Comment: @ManishNegi it gives 0 no value for jsonArray route

Comment: can you paste the message here?

Comment: JSONArray routesArray = resultObj.getJSONArray("routes"); Error point to this line

Comment: for which jsonArray you're getting this error.. array or legs?
whichever array it is doesn't have any values

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are also getting something like this too in your JSON response apart from 0 for the duration.

```
{"status":"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT","routes":[]}.
```

This means that you are exceeding the limits of the Direction API usage. Please note that for standard version there are only 2,500 free directions requests per day available. If you need to request more, their are additional charges associated.

Check the official documentation on [Google Maps Directions API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits) more details.